# How to provide unique id to get match details with CricAPI?

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, afnetworking, afhttpsessionmanager

I am working with CricAPI to get list of upcoming matches.

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://cricapi.com/api/matches/?apikey=Gxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx2"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url ];

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager GET:[url absoluteString]
  parameters:nil
     success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id JSON)
```

Its working fine, providing JSON output.

How can I get the score details of a particular match ? It says you have to provide "unique_id" of the match, I am not sure where to use it ?

Comment: Found out myself, just had to pass parameters:

      NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url ];
       NSDictionary *para = @{@"unique_id":self.id2};
          AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
       manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    [manager GET:[url absoluteString]
      parameters:para
         success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id JSON)

Answer (score 0):

You have to click on new match API or OLD match API from there you will get unique id of that match which you can use for your next query